# using onLongClickListener to change values quickly

Tags: java, android, button, listener, wear-os

I'm trying to create a set of buttons that will change a value up or down by 1 with a single tap, and change the value quickly by holding the button. I can't figure out how to get the value to change quickly. Here's what I have:

```
    btPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mTempo=mTempo+1;
        setTempo(mTempo + 1);
        tvTempo.setText(Integer.toString(mTempo));
      }  
    });
    btPlus.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view) {
            mTempo = mTempo + 1;
            setTempo(mTempo + 1);
            tvTempo.setText(Integer.toString(mTempo));
        }
    });                              
    btMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mTempo=mTempo-1;
            setTempo(mTempo - 1);
            tvTempo.setText(Integer.toString(mTempo));
        }
    });
    btMinus.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view) {
            mTempo = mTempo - 1;
            setTempo(mTempo - 1);
            tvTempo.setText(Integer.toString(mTempo));
        }
    });    
    return rootView;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holding the button is something else than long clicking it. You need an  [`onTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

In the onPressed method check if the MotionEvent is UP or DOWN and then start/stop counting.

EDIT: Try Counting up in a Thread, something like that:

```
Final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
       @Override public void run(){
          while(!t.isInterrupted(){
             setTempo(mTempo++);
          }
       }
switch (event){
case ACTION_DOWN: 
       t.start();
       break;
case ACTION_UP:
       t.interrupt();
       break
}
```

Comment: I can understand using onTouchListener, but I'm still struggling with how to get it to count continuously while the button is pressed. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: You can start a new Thread on DOWN and start it. on UP you Interrupt it. The Thread counts in a while not interrupted loop your mTempo

Comment: Mind helping a little bit more? It says t is accessed from an inner class and needs to be declared final in the first case and then that t might not have been initalized in the second case.

Comment: Yes, thats right, did some changes in the answer. t is noe final and initialized at the beginning. You might put the Thread declaration outside the onPressed method.